# Handle links via mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to short my URLs via **mod_rewrite**.

There are two types of URL on my website: One time with parameter and  without parameters.

1. example.com/devel/pages/event.php?event=MYEVENTNAME
2. example.com/devel/pages/image.php?event=MYEVENTNAME
3. example.com/devel/pages/location.php?name=MYLOCATION
4. example.com/devel/pages/home.php
5. example.com/devel/pages/news.php

I would like to call the sites like:

1. example.com/devel/events/MYEVENTNAME
2. example.com/devel/images/MYEVENTNAME
3. example.com/devel/locations/MYLOCATION
4. example.com/devel/home
5. example.com/devel/news

This is what I have write right now…

e.g.

```
RewriteRule devel/images/(.*)?$ devel/pages/images.php?event=$1
```

How is it possible as to do it on the right way?

Comment: What's not working with this rule?

Comment: With this rule the first URLs are working (devel/events/MYEVENTNAME). Can i add a rule (additionally) for the shorter URLs? 
Like: RewriteRule devel/(.*)?$ devel/pages/$1.php?

Answer (score 2):

You can use these 2 generic rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^devel/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ devel/pages/$1.php?event=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^devel/([\w-]+)/?$ devel/pages/$1.php [L,NC]
```